# Use split function to split recursively in python

Tags: python-3.x, split

I have written a piece of code which takes a keyword and splits a name using that specific keyword, however as split returns the list, now I want to individually check the elements of the returned list and again split it using a different keyword(if it exists), but this time I dont want another sublist to be returned, rather then the elements should get extended in the same list.

Code below :-

```
def get_comb_drugs(keyword, name):

    if keyword in name:
        name = name.split(keyword)

    return name

print(get_comb_drugs(", polymer with", "Acetaldehyde, polymer with ammonia and formaldehyde"))
```

The output I get is:

```
['Acetaldehyde', ' ammonia and formaldehyde']
```

however, I want to split `'ammonia and formaldehyde'` again using `" and "` keyword and the exact output I want is:

```
['Acetaldehyde', ' ammonia', 'formaldehyde']
```

Guide me in achieving the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.split` instead with an alternation pattern:

```
import re
separators = [', polymer with', ' and ']
re.split('|'.join(separators), 'Acetaldehyde, polymer with ammonia and formaldehyde')
```

This returns:

```
['Acetaldehyde', ' ammonia', 'formaldehyde']
```

Comment: Yep, but I cannot explicitly pass ', polymer with' and other pattern. I have lots of such keywords.

Comment: You can join these separators into an alternation pattern with the `'|'.join` method, as shown in my edited answer.

Comment: I get your point, but I need to pass many such keywords which I have in a single function which checks and returns the elements in a single list.

Comment: @Rajsxx When I said you can use `'|'.join` to join the separators I meant the separators as a list, exactly what you say you need. I've edited my answer so that you can see the point more clearly.